# Label data using a combination of 2 columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student ID': [123456,789456,101112,131415],
                       'Math ': [3,2,4,2],
                       'Art  ': [3,3,3,1]})
```

I want to look into the combination of the exams and label each student as follows:

incase the student got:

- 1 in Math and 2 in Art (or vise versa) then labelled "Usatisfactory"
- 3 in Math and 3 in Art (or vise versa) then labelled "Good"
- 3 in Math and 4 in Art (or vise versa) then labelled "Good"
- 2 in Math and 3 in Art (or vise versa) then labelled "Moderate"

| Student ID | Math | Art | combined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 3 | 3 | 33 |
| 789456 | 2 | 3 | 23 |
| 101112 | 4 | 3 | 43 |
| 131415 | 2 | 1 | 21 |

What I did, is created the combined column using the following code:

## Create a new column and concatenate data

```
cols = ['Math', 'Art',]
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

## convert 'combined' column to integer

```
df['combined']  = df['combined'] .astype('int')
```

## Create a combination for score

```
unsat    =[11]
moderate =[12,21,22]
good     =[33,34,43]
excellent=[45,54,55]
```

so if the score is 11 or (1 for math and 1 for Art) he/she will get unsatisfactory
if the student got any combination of 33 or 34 then moderate and so on.

I am unable to know how to use my logic to label my data. I feel that my way is way too complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you allow *vice verse*, math 1 art 2 is equal to math 2 art 1, which means you can simply use `sum`:

```
mapper = {3: "Unsatisfactory",
          6: "Good",
          7: "Good",
          5: "Moderate"}

df["label"] = df["Math"].add(df["Art"]).replace(mapper)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Student ID  Math  Art           label
0      123456     3    3            Good
1      789456     2    3        Moderate
2      101112     4    3            Good
3      131415     2    1  Unsatisfactory
```